# Conditional case in SQL query

Tags: mysql

My table design is next

```
table oc_za_puni_uredjaj
sif_company  (integer - primary, value for company)
sif_device   (integer - primary, value for device)
sif_nos      (integer - primary, value for customer)
sif_mp       (integer - primary, value for customer's place)
rbr          (integer - primary, value for customer's place item)
ocitano      (integer - 0 - empty, 1 - full)
datum        (date    - date of the record)
area         (text    - name of area of customer)
```

Example of data in database is next

```
sif_company | sif_device | sifnos | sif_mp | rbr | ocitano | datum | area |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |     1      | 1      | 1      | 1   | 1       |...    |abcd
1           |     1      | 1      | 2      | 1   | 0       |...    |abcd
1           |     1      | 2      | 1      | 1   | 1       |...    |abc
1           |     1      | 1      | 2      | 1   | 1       |...    |abcd
1           |     1      | 1      | 2      | 3   | 1       |...    |abcd
```

My existing query which works (for some cases) is next

```
SELECT area as naselje, 
    count(*) total, 
    sum(case when ocitano = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ocitano 
FROM `oc_za_puni_uredjaj` 
WHERE sif_company = 1 group by 1
```

The result looks like

```
naselje    |  total    |    ocitano
------------------------------------
abc        |  1        |     1
abcd       |  4        |     3
```

The problem is if i have same data for 2 different devices (`sif_device`). I could have data in table like below

```
sif_company | sif_device | sifnos | sif_mp | rbr | ocitano | datum | area |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1           |     2      | 1      | 1      | 1   | 0       |...    |abcd
1           |     1      | 2      | 1      | 1   | 1       |...    |abcd
1           |     2      | 2      | 1      | 1   | 1       |...    |abcd
1           |     1      | 3      | 1      | 1   | 1       |...    |abc
```

My desired output for that data should look like

```
naselje    |  total    |    ocitano
------------------------------------
abc        |  1        |     1
abcd       |  2        |     2
```

So if i have in table row with (`sif_nos`, `sif_mp`, `rbr`) for different device (`sif_device`) then i have cases:

- if only one of them has `ocitano = 1` then for that area i have to **increment ocitano in output** by 1 (there could be even one row just for one device)
- if there is several rows with `ocitano = 1` then i have to **increment ocitano in output** by 1
- if all of them got `ocitano = 0` then i **don't increment ocitano in output**

**EDIT**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4b63)

Any help would be nice

**EDIT 2**

For example, if i have 3 devices, (1,2 and 3), there could be row with (`sif_nos`, `sif_mp`, `rbr`) for 1 device, for 2 device or for all (all 3 devices) and so on.

Comment: create a sqlfiddle so that a conditional aggregation can be simply applied against it for verification

Comment: @Drew Added SQL fiddle in question

Comment: Awesome thx hopefully someone will zoom by soon and I will take a look in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Schema (from your fiddle)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oc_za_puni_uredjaj` (
  `sif_company` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sif_device` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sif_nos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sif_mp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `rbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `ocitano` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datum` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`sif_company`,`sif_device`,`sif_nos`,`sif_mp`,`rbr`)
);


insert into `oc_za_puni_uredjaj` values 
(1,1,1,1,1,1,"2016-05-24 12:01:49","abcd"), 
(1,2,1,1,1,0,"2016-05-24 12:01:41","abcd"),
(1,1,2,1,1,1,"2016-05-24 12:01:43","abcd"),
(1,2,2,1,1,1,"2016-05-24 12:01:48","abcd"), 
(1,1,3,1,1,1,"2016-05-24 12:01:46","abc");
```

### Query

```
select naselje,total,sum(ocitano1) as ocitano
from
(   SELECT area as naselje, sif_device, 
        count(*) total, 
        least(sum(case when ocitano = 1 then 1 else 0 end),1) ocitano1 -- max out at one
    FROM `oc_za_puni_uredjaj` 
    WHERE sif_company = 1
    group by area,sif_device
) xDerived
group by naselje,total
order by naselje;
```

### Results

```
+---------+-------+---------+
| naselje | total | ocitano |
+---------+-------+---------+
| abc     |     1 |       1 |
| abcd    |     2 |       2 |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

`xDerived` is merely an alias name. Every derived table requires an alias otherwise an error occurs. The `least` function limits the counting for `ocitano` when grouped by `area,sif_device`.

It does hit your desired results. Hopefully when you throw more test data at it, the routine does what you meant, which could be interpreted a few ways.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It works on data which i provided but there could be records which are only on 1 device or on all devices. So if you remove first insert in SQL fiddle you should get the same result but it returns for one area two rows in result. To test it in SQL fiddle just comment first or second insert in schema.

Comment: Right, that is why it is important to have a clear question, all boundary conditions in data, and show all expected results. I hit what you asked for, no?

Comment: Well i tried to be as much clear as i could. Well you solved my problem if i have always data for all devices. But in my case that is not always 100% case that i'll have that so i have to cover that other case also

Comment: Is it possible to make your query works for that case also or i have to ask a new question?

Comment: Let me look at your edit and see if it makes sense to me. If so, or if I think so, I will ask you here and change my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114752/discussion-between-drew-and-kukec).

Comment: I put my comments in the chat link above

Comment: i added description for cases in question